# Yii2 rest create - saving to DB

Tags: rest, yii2

I am trying to save data from the form using yii2 rest api controller, standard create action. New line is created in DB, and id is returned, but data from POST is not saved - only zeroes appear in DB, then I overrided create action by my own one, the same situation. But if I directly save to DB, without rest api controller, data is saved successfully.
What can be a reason of such strange saving to DB? Thanks! 
By the way, in index I can see post data in the format: {"_csrf":"wergferw","table_name":{"sum":25000,"currency":1}}

Controller is very simple:

```
namespace frontend\controllers;
use yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\web\Response;


class DemandController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'frontend\models\Demands';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['formats']['application/json']   
        =   Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

I get reply in rest:

```
<response><id>37</id></response>
```

Model is generated by gii

```
namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;

class Demands extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'demands';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['sum', 'currency'], 'required'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'sum' => 'Sum',
            'currency' => 'Currency',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your controller and model? I suspect the issue lies somewhere in there.

Comment: How do you load the data to the model?

Answer (score 0):

If none of the posted data appears in the database, it sounds like a post format issue to me. Check that your HTTP Post headers have "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: Yes, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, how can it be changed? May be I should send POST data using ajax and change there to Json?

Comment: You need to be able to control the http headers from the tool or language you are using to send the post.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the problem so after changing this line it's worked for me..
You try to change the model->load() method inside  yii/rest/createAction

```
public function run()
{


    $model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');
    change this line to 
    $model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams());


 }
```

see this link for more info - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail

The model->load($data,$formName) - the $data should be $_GET or $_POST value of array and $formName   use to load the data into the model. If not set, formName() is used. so u have to change the model->load() in createAction class.

Comment: well.. as a result, my collegue wrote his own create method, out of the box was not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Better you have to override the activecontroller default create action then try

```
 class CabController extends ActiveController
   {
       public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Cab';

        public function actions(){

            $actions = parent::actions(); 
            unset($actions['create']);
            unset($actions['update']);
            unset($actions['index']);          
            return $actions;
       }

    /* Declare methods supported by APIs */
      protected function verbs(){
          return [
            'create' => ['POST'],
            'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH','POST'],
            'delete' => ['DELETE'],
            'view' => ['GET'],
            'index'=>['GET'],

        ];


    }
    public function actionCreate(){ 

        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $model = new Cab;
        $post_data = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $model->load($post_data);   
        $model->save(false);            
        return $model;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include safe columns in your model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['sum', 'currency'], 'safe'],
    ];
 }
```